# sap.m.Shell & sap.ui.commons.ApplicationHeader <div> issue

Tags: sapui5

I set up the Application in a shell as follows in the **index.html**

```
new sap.m.Shell({
   app : new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
     height : "100%",                               
     name : "xx.xx.xx"
   })
}).placeAt("content");
```

Is it possible to also add the application header control to this?

```
//create the ApplicationHeader control
var oAppHeader = new sap.ui.commons.ApplicationHeader("appHeader");
//configure the branding area

oAppHeader.setLogoSrc("http://www.sap.com/global/images/SAPLogo.gif");
oAppHeader.setLogoText("Logo Text");

//configure the welcome area
oAppHeader.setDisplayWelcome(true);
oAppHeader.setUserName(userFullName);

//configure the log off area
oAppHeader.setDisplayLogoff(true);

oAppHeader.placeAt("content");
```

When I added that before the Shell or in the main, it appears fine but the screen size has increased beyond 100% and so you have to scroll to see the footer (or the application header, depending where it's placed)

This is the **Main.view.xml** & **Main.controller.js**

```
 <core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
               xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="emc.ui.sc.view.Main"
   displayBlock="true" height="100%" >
            <App id="idMain">
            </App>
    </core:View>

    sap.ui.controller("emc.ui.sc.view.Main", {
        onInit : function() {
            if (sap.ui.Device.support.touch === false) {
                this.getView().addStyleClass("sapUiSizeCompact");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Shell is - as the name indicates - intended to be used as root control. So the ApplicationHeader must be contained in the Shell. Why don't you use
the [Unified Shell](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.unified.Shell/about)?

Comment: hi Matbt, i can add the application header inside the main (which is inside the shell), it was more the scrolling issue with the screen size extended beyond 100%. I was really asking if these are compatible or is it better to use a shell (Like the unified) that has header properties available to use. On the unified shell itself, it states "Do not use this control within applications which run inside the Fiori Lauchpad and do not use it for other scenarios than the root control usecase", I'm not sure I want to limit my app in this way.